# To detect the image/frame in the video

Tags: image, opencv, video, ffmpeg

I was given two inputs one is an image (image from .mp4 video file)and the other one is video(mostly in .ts format). Mostly the video is lossy encoding. I need to find the image in the video. Here I can't compare the raw frames of video and image as they are different in encoding . To my knowledge,  I need to find same alike image/frame in the video with respect to image. Is there any tools/api to find the image in the video.

Comment: you might be able to convert the mp4 to "a lot of images" then compare your image with those.  imagemagick might have some "compare image x with y" option you could use, gl!

Answer (score 0):

Detect [features](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_detection/feature_detection.html) and try to establish a [homography](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html#feature-homography).

Then pick the frame with the most homography inliers (the cv::findHomography function has an output parameter named `mask`)